# Can I setup my dojo dijit form ComboButton to do a onClick or something similar when the user selects a value in the drop down list?

Tags: javascript, combobox, dojo, dijit.form

I think I may be using the wrong `dojo` widget. I just need a dropdown list really, but currently have setup a `ComboButton`. Can I setup an `onClick` or onSelect of some sort when the user picks an option inside the `ComboButton` down down menu? My current `onClick` is picking up when the user clicks on the text area button, but not the drop down arrow selection. I want an `onClick` or onSelect action after the user clicks the down arrow button and then selects an option.

```
            {id: 'identOpModeId', field: 'identOpMode', name:'OpMode', width: '124px',
                navigable: true,
                expandLevel: 'all',
                widgetsInCell: true,
                allowEventBubble: true,
                onCellWidgetCreated: function(cellWidget, cell){
                    var menuItems = OpModeMenuItems.returnOpModeMenuItems(cellWidget);
                    menuItems.forEach( function (menuItem)
                    {
                        cellWidget.sMenu.addChild(menuItem);
                    });
                },
                setCellValue: function(one,two,cellWidget){
                    var rowIndex = cellWidget.cell.row.id;
                    cellWidget.identOpMode.set("label", identMemStore.get(rowIndex).identOpMode);
                },
                getCellWidgetConnects: function(cellWidget, cell){
                    // return an array of connection arguments
                    return [

                        // How do I capture the onClick of the dijitArrowButton button??

                        [cellWidget.identOpMode, 'onClick', function(e){
                            var rowIndex = cellWidget.cell.row.id;
                            // I do NOT need this line - the drop down menu already sets the value! I just need to update the store!!
                            //cellWidget.identOpMode.set("label", identMemStore.get(rowIndex).identOpMode);
                            identMemStore.data[rowIndex-1].identOpMode = identMemStore.get(rowIndex).identOpMode;
                            // cellWidget.data[rowIndex].identOpMode = identMemStore.get(rowIndex).identOpMode;
                            // Add item to userRowChanges
                            updateRows(rowIndex-1, identGridx.row(rowIndex-1).item());
                        }]
                    ];
                },
                decorator: function(){
                    return [
                        '<div data-dojo-attach-point="identOpMode" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ComboButton" >',
                        '<div data-dojo-attach-point="sMenu" data-dojo-type="dijit/Menu"></div></div>'
                    ].join('');
                }

            },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the onChange event and not the onClick and you might be looking for a DropDownButton instead of a ComboButton but either way, onChange is the method you should be looking for. A good way to hook into the onChange method is to use "dojo/on" and do something like this:

```
on(this.identOpMode, "change", function() {
   //Do something here
});
```

In your specific situation, I would actually modify the [cellWidget.identOpMode, 'onClick' part to be 'onChange' instead.

Comment: Thanks, where would I place the code? I've tried several things with no luck.

Comment: I just updated my answer above to give you a better idea of what you can do.

Comment: Your suggestion to change onClick to onChange worked. I didn't use the `dojo/on` as you suggested. Please see my posted answer as to what I did exactly. But thanks, you helped me solve it. I may not have solved it the most correct way but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Richard suggestion is spot on. From his suggestion and what I have learned, `dojo/on` is the correction solution. Here is my solution, using the `dijit/form/ComboButton` though I may change to a `DropDownBox` in the future, for now it's working, so I'll leave it.

For my `dijit/form/ComboButton`, I simply added code to my `onClick` for each item in the list to grab the data change.

```
returnOpModeMenuItems: function (CellWidget)
{
    var menu = [];
    var labels = ["Label1","Label2","Label3"];
    labels.forEach( function (label)
    {
        var menuItem = new dijit.MenuItem({
            label : label,
            value : label,
            onClick : function (value) {
                CellWidget.identOpMode.set('label', label);

                var rowIndex = CellWidget.cell.row.id;
                identMemStore.data[rowIndex-1].identOpMode = label;

                updateRows(rowIndex-1, identGridx.row(rowIndex-1).item());
            }
        });
        menu.push(menuItem);
    });
    return menu;
}
```

For other dojo widgets that don't have onClick's I used the following:

```
                { id: 'srcSelVideoFrameRateId', field: 'srcSelVideoFrameRate', name: 'Frame Rate', width: '77px',
                    widgetsInCell: true,
                    navigable: true,
                    setCellValue: function(gridData, storeData, cellWidget){
                        var rowIndex = cellWidget.cell.row.index()+1;
                        var spinnerVal = sourceSelVideoTabMemStore.get(rowIndex).srcSelVideoFrameRate;

                        cellWidget.srcSelVideoFrameRate.set('style', "width:55px");
                        cellWidget.srcSelVideoFrameRate.set('value', spinnerVal);
                    },
                    getCellWidgetConnects: function(cellWidget, cell){
                        // return an array of connection arguments
                        return [
                            [cellWidget.srcSelVideoFrameRate, 'onChange', function(e){
                                var rowIndex = cellWidget.cell.row.id;
                                sourceSelVideoTabMemStore.data[rowIndex-1].srcSelVideoFrameRate = cellWidget.srcSelVideoFrameRate.displayedValue;

                                // Add item to userRowChanges
                                updateRows(rowIndex-1, srcSelVideoGridx.row(rowIndex-1).item());
                            }]
                        ];
                    },
                    decorator: function(){
                        return "<input data-dojo-type='dijit/form/NumberSpinner' data-dojo-props='smallDelta:0.1, largeDelta:1.0, constraints:{min:1,max:24,places:1,round:false},' data-dojo-attach-point='srcSelVideoFrameRate' />";
                    }
                },
```

For basic text editable fields I use the following:

```
srcSelVideoGridx.edit.connect(srcSelVideoGridx.edit, "onApply", function(cell, success) {
    var item = cell.row.data();
    var rowId = cell.row.id-1;
    console.log('Row with ID ' + rowId + ' is modified. New value: ' + item);
    updateRows(rowId, item);
});
```